# Facebook GetEvents graph api

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am writing an android app and i need to integrate the add events functionality into that. i searched the graph api documentation for how to post the data but when i tried that i am getting FileNotFound eception. i am POSTing required data to the URL "https://graph.facebook.com/me/events". It wouldof great help if anyone could give me small code snippet.. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

The code looks like the following:

Bundle params = new Bundle();

params.putString("name", "My event");
params.putString("location", "somewhere,test");
params.putString("start_time", "2011-07-29T10:13:00");
params.putString("end_time", "2010-07-29T10:20:00");

facebook.request("me/events", params, "POST");

I hope that this code will help you :)